# Can you open a PDF written in LaTeX, on Dia, and edit it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

I am writing a diagram in LaTeX with TikZ, and I would like to compile the LaTeX code, and make it view on Dia to make some adjustments, manually.

Any clues on how to achieve this?

Comment: wouldn't you want to generate the dia form rather than PDF I haven't used dia much but it's not really a pdf editor is it?

Comment: export the tikz as svg and import svg into dia is your most likely route